# Normal bundle of a section of a $\mathbb{P}^1$-bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a normal projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$ and let $\mathcal{L}$ be an ample line bundle on $X$.

If we define $P=\mathbb{P}_X(\mathcal{O}_X\oplus \mathcal{L})$, then the quotient $\mathcal{O}_X\oplus \mathcal{L} \to \mathcal{O}_X$ corresponds to a section of the natural projection $\pi:P\to X$. Let's denote this section by $D\cong X \subseteq P$, which is a Cartier divisor on $P$.

How can we compute the normal bundle $\mathcal{N}_{D/P}$?

This bundle will be a line bundle in this case, I was wondering if we can relate it to $\mathcal{L}$.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how such normal bundles are calculated. Let $\pi:P\to X$ and $\mathcal{O}_P(1)$, the relative ample bundle. We have $\pi^*(\mathcal{O}_X\oplus\mathcal{L})\to\mathcal{O}_P(1)$, the canonical surjective map. The surjection $\mathcal{O}_X\oplus\mathcal{L}\to \mathcal{O}_X$ has kernel $\mathcal{L}$ and thus we get a map $\pi^*\mathcal{L}\to\mathcal{O}_P(1)$ and then the cokernel is supported on $D$ (this is how $D$ is defined) and we get an exact sequence, $0\to \pi^*\mathcal{L}(-1)\to\mathcal{O}_P\to\mathcal{O}_D\to 0$. The normal bundle is $\pi^*\mathcal{L}^{-1}(1)\otimes \mathcal{O}_D$, which is just $\mathcal{L}^{-1}$ (identifying $D$ with $X$), snce $\mathcal{O}_D(1)$ is just $\mathcal{O}_D$.