# Normal bundle of a section of a projective bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Let $X=\mathbb{P}^1$, $E=\mathcal{O}\oplus\mathcal{O}(1)\oplus \mathcal{O}(2)$ and let $Y=\mathbb{P}(E)$. Denote $\pi:Y\to X$ the projection map. There is a section of $\pi$ corresponding to the surjection $E\to \mathcal{O}$. Let $C$ be the image of this section in $Y$. How can we compute the normal bundle of this curve?

The case when $E$ is a rank 2 vector bundle is discussed here.[Normal bundle of a section of a $\mathbb{P}^1$-bundle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1353627/normal-bundle-of-a-section-of-a-mathbbp1-bundle). However, I believe in our case, the argument cannot be directly applied.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just checking: For you, is the projectivization of a vector space a space of lines (as in topology/differential geometry), or a space of hyperplanes (as in algebraic geometry)?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I believe I am using the one in algebraic geometry.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let us do this more generally, so that we do not have to look at many cases. Let $E$ be a vector bundle on a scheme $X$ and assume we have an exact sequence $0\to F\to E\to L\to 0$, with $L$ a line bundle. This gives a section $D$ of $\pi:P=\mathbb{P}_X(E)\to X$, the projective bundle. Let us calculate the normal bundle of $D$ in $P$.

We have a natural map $\pi^*F\to \mathcal{O}_P(1)$ and one easily checks that the cokernel is just $\mathcal{O}_D(1)$, which can easily seen to be $L$ (identifying $D$ with $X$). So, we get a surjection $\pi^*(F\otimes L^{-1})\to I_D$, the ideal sheaf of $D\subset P$. Since codimension of $D$ is just the rank of $F$, we see that $D$ is a local complete intersection, coming from a correct rank vector bundle. Thus the normal bundle of $D$ then is just $F^*\otimes L$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Everything is clear except that I am a little confused about the statement that cokernel of the $\pi^*F\to\mathcal{O}_P(1)$ is $\mathcal{O}_D(1)$. Could you explain a little on this?

Comment: This gives a map $\pi^*F(-1)\to\mathcal{O}_P$ whose image thus is an ideal. This ideal defines $D$ (that is in fact the definition of $D$), so the cokernel is just $\mathcal{O}_D$, so twisting back, you get what you want.

Comment: Why the normal bundle of $D$ results $F^*\otimes L$?

Comment: @user34977 If a vector bundle $G$ of rank $r$ maps onto a local complete intersection ideal sheaf $I$ of height $r$ defining a codimension $r$ scheme $D$, the surjection $G\to I$ when restricted to $D$ gives $G_{|D}\to I/I^2\to 0$. But, both are rank $r$ vectorbundles on $D$ and thus they are isomorphic. $I/I^2$ is the co-normal bundle and so the normal bundle is just $G^*_{|D}$.