# Canonical map $\pi^{*}E \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(E)}(1)$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a complex manifold and $E\rightarrow X$ a holomorphic vector bundle of rank $n+1$. Consider the projectivization $\pi: \mathbb{P}(E) \rightarrow X$ of this bundle, where our "projectization" is a $\mathbb{CP}^{n}$-bundle over $X$ whose fiber over $x\in X$ is the projectivization of the vector space $E_{x}$.

In papers, the "canonical" map $\pi^{*}E \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(E)}(1)$ is defined and used. 
Here, $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(E)}(1)$ is the hyperplane bundle over $\mathbb{P}(E)$. My question is:  How can one define this map canonically? I wonder why one does not need a metric on $\pi^{*}E$. With such a metric, although it depends on its choice, one can define a map $\pi^{*}E \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(E)}(1)$. Can you define the map without it?

I appreciate your answer, and any comments are welcome. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There are two conventions about $\mathbb{P}(E)$ in the literature: in the first the fiber over $x$ is the space of lines in $E_x$, and in the second (so-called Grothendieck's convention) the fiber is the space of hyperplanes in $E_x$.
It is important don't to confuse between the two conventions.

In the Grothendieck's convention, one has $\pi_*(\mathcal{O}(1)) \cong E$, hence by adjunction there is a canonical morphism $\pi^*E \to \mathcal{O}(1)$.

In the other convention, one has $\pi_*(\mathcal{O}(1)) \cong E^\vee$, hence by adjunction there is a canonical morphism $\pi^*E^\vee \to \mathcal{O}(1)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering the question. So I seemed to confuse two conventions. Let me make sure. How about $\mathcal{O}_{P}(1)$ in the answer given by Mohan https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2317869/normal-bundle-of-a-section-of-a-projective-bundle ? Which did he use the first or second convention? The map $\pi^{*}F \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{P}(1)$ in his answer must be related to our canonical map.

Comment: He is using the Grothendieck's convention; the map $\pi^*F \to \mathcal{O}_P(1)$ is the composition of $\pi^*F \to \pi^*E$ with the canonical map $\pi^*E \to \mathcal{O}_P(1)$.

Comment: Thanks! Now I am convinced.